# how to create a toml array usng helm template?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a configmap which contains a toml file

something like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  burrow.toml: |
    [zookeeper]
    servers=[abc.2181, cde.2181]
    timeout=6
    root-path="/burrow"
```

When I am trying to create a helm chart to generate this configmap, I was putting something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  burrow.toml: |
    [zookeeper]
    servers={{ .Values.config.zookeeperServers }}
    timeout=6
    root-path="/burrow"
```

and in the values.yaml, I put:

```
  zookeeperServers: [ "abc.2181", "cde.2181"]
```

However, the rendered value became:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  burrow.toml: |
    [zookeeper]
    servers=[abc.2181 cde.2181]
    timeout=6
    root-path="/burrow"
```

The comma is missing. Is there a good way to template this correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution, in the values.yaml
put

```
zookeeperServers: |
[ "abc.2181", "cde.2181"]
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, `servers=[{{ .Values.config.zookeeperServers | join "," }}]`. Quoting could get weird if you put TOML metachars in those values, but for simple things it should work.